# Redirect all *.php pages to *.html through .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have one html site and I want to redirect all `php pages` to `html pages`.

How to rewrite some php pages to html pages through htaccess. I have around 8000 html pages and 500 php pages. I want to rewrite the php pages to .htm. I have added some code in htaccess but our html pages not working properly. It only shows menu field and inner page not visible properly.

I am using below code-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Does swapping the positions of `.php` and `.html` in your code do anything? Such as `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.html`?

Answer (score 1):

make sure mod rewrite is enabled

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

if you also need to redirect each php page to html

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Allan, I have used this code in htaccess but not redirect properly.